# Replace a key in an object while spreading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, spread

I have the below object,

```
const obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  .
  .
  .
  .
  'z': 26
}
```

I want to have a new object which will contain all the keys as object `obj`, but instead of one specific key, I want it to be replaced with another key, say I want to omit key `'a'` and replace it with `'new_a'`. Below way doesn't remove the original key `'a'`. Is there a way in which I can achieve it with aliasing? Or deleting key `'a'` is the only option?

```
const obj2 = {
   ...obj,
   'new_a': 111
}
```

I want obj2 to be like this-

```
{
   'new_a': 111,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3,
   .
   .
   .
   .
   'z': 26 
}
```

Comment: If they key doesn't need to be `new_a` you can just simply overwrite it like `const obj2 = { ...obj, 'a': 111 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it in a single step (single *line*, sure, but not a single step). Destructuring with rest followed by assignment does it nicely though:

```
const {a, ...obj2} = obj;
obj2.new_a = obj.a; // Or just `= a;`, either way
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4,
    // ...
    'z': 26
};
const {a, ...obj2} = obj;
obj2.new_a = obj.a;
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Here's a oneliner `const obj2 = (({a: newA, ...rest}) => ({newA, ...rest}))(obj)`

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want **new_a** to have the same value as **a** then:

```
const obj2 = { ...obj, new_a: 111 };
delete obj2["a"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the cleanest approach, but a single-liner:

```js
const obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'z': 26
}

let obj2 = { 
    'new_a': 111, 
    ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => key !== 'a'))
};

console.log(obj2);
```

This way you don't have to `delete` any key and you don't have to "copy" the original `a` to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iife and the object rest spread operator to collect all but the renamed properties and spread to add them to a new object.
<sub>[mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for reference.</sub>

`const obj2 = (({a: newA, ...rest}) => ({newA, ...rest}))(obj)`

---

For readabilities sake you might want to consider writing adapter functions, it's quite and describes the transformation of the objects properties pretty well.

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3, d: 4};

const adapter = ({a: newA, ...rest}) => ({newA, ...rest});

const obj2 = {
  ...adapter(obj), 
}

console.log(obj2);
```